# Reconhecimento de colisões

Tags: unity3d

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]estou desenvolvendo por meio de tutorias o jogo do Unity training day (Nightmares) e percebi que o player não reconhecia colisões nos objetos.

Ao adicionar o componente "Capsule Collider", o erro foi consertado, porém o personagem passa a se mover sozinho. Onde está o erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;

    Vector3 movement;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    int floorMask;
    float camRayLenght = 100f;

    void Awake ()
    {
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();

    }


    void Update ()
    {
        float h =Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v =Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Move (h,v);
        Turning ();
        Animating (h, v);

    }


    void Move (float h, float v)
    {

        movement.Set (h, 0f, v);

        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime  ;

        playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);

    }

    void Turning ()
    {

        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if(Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask))
        {

            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);

            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotation);
        }




    }


    void Animating (float h,float v)
    {

        bool walking = h != 0f || v !=0f;

        anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
    }
}
```

[image: <code>inserir a descrição da imagem aqui</code>]
[image: Capsule Collider]

Comment: Olá @pedrofarah, poderia mandar mais informações sobre o player, por favor".
Se mover sozinho não é algo exclusivo do collider, se possível mande a captura do Inspector do player completo, do código do player, e veja se existe algum outro script/componente que afeta o player indiretamente, dependendo da parte do tutorial você tem os ataques que ele sofre, e hud.(mas eu acho que só no inspector, e código do player vamos achar a solução.

Comment: Informações adicionadas ai nils!

Comment: Parece tudo em ordem, vou te pedir alguns favores.
1 - O que está escrito na Tag e no Layer do player?

2 - Tem um `v` do lado do capsule collider, clica nele para desmarcar veja se ele parou de andar.

3 - Mande o Ispector do floor (dentro de Environment).

4 - Você chegou a fazer o passo do nav mesh?

Comment: Nils ,na Tag está "Player" e em Layer está "Default" . Se o v é desmarcado o player para de andar sozinho porém as colisões naão são reconhecidas e ainda não cheguei nesse passo..adicionei mais algumas informações

Comment: Muito estranho isso, não era para acontecer este problema se você fez igual ao vídeo. E o transform do teu player? Veja se ele não tá se arrastando abaixo do chão. E arrume esta tua pergunta, está uma bagunça, e com imagens duplicadas.

Comment: A propósito, o se mover sozinho é de andar pelo mapa, ou de tocar a animação de que você está andando? Você tem algum controle plugado no teu pc? Além do teclado e mouse?

Comment: Pedro, esta pergunta está bem difícil de responder porque, novamente, você não detalha o seu problema de uma forma clara. Talvez porque como você está ainda aprendendo não entende o que ocorre da forma correta. Veja, o seu título não diz nada (só diz "reconhecimento de colisões"). Depois, diz que esse problema (do título) foi corrigido, e que o problema é que o personagem se "move sozinho". Como o colega @Nils já mencionou, o que é "se move sozinho"? O objeto translada pela tela (literalmente se move), ou a animação do andar é executada e ele fica parado?

Comment: Não leve a mal, mas como você tá seguindo um vídeo de qualidade muito provavelmente o problema é (mais uma vez) uma falta de atenção sua em algum aspecto. Apesar da boa vontade, este site não é um fórum e não dá pra ficarmos experimentando todas as combinações possíveis contigo. Procure ser mais claro no problema (e sem repetir imagens, como já sugerido). Também, procure rever o vídeo e refazer os seus passos (verificando as configurações/o código), prestando atenção nos detalhes.

Comment: Além disso, é um tanto frustrante insistir em te ajudar pra descobrir que foi uma mera falta de atenção. Além do mais, isso não colabora para a qualidade de conteúdo do site, pois os problemas tendem a não servirem para ajudar outras pessoas. Ah, e também não colabora para o seu aprendizado, pois é o processo de tentativa e erro ocorre quase que exclusivamente pela parte de outros (que já sabem) e não de quem deveria estar realmente interessado (você, que ainda não sabe tanto). :)